# Trigger.io: iOS 9 iPad Multitasking error

Tags: ios, trigger.io

**UPDATE: This problem is now solved by using the latest version of Trigger.io**

This question is about how to get around the ITMS-90475 error using Trigger.io (and not xcode).

After the release of iOS 9, i get the following error when submitting an app to the App Store that is built using Trigger.io/Forge:

`ERROR ITMS-90475: "Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires launch story board in bundle`

I am developing on linux, and not using xcode to upload my app. From other stackoverflow answers (e.g. this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32563605/1030104) I see one solution is to disable multitasking support using xcode.

Does anyone know whether this is possible to do using only Trigger.io and not xcode?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32561780/1024108), your bundle should be valid if you deactivate multitasking for your app. Add this to your Info.plist:

```
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
<string>YES</string>
```

As you're using Trigger.io, this means you have to edit the Info.plist file in between `forge build` and `forge package` either programatically (as part of your build process) or by editing the file manually.

Answer (score 0):

For your target, check Requires Full Screen on the General Page:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

try adding the bellow code to the `info.plist`

```
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and above(@patrick's) answer?

Comment: Yea you better check with the **tags** @patrick's it was `<string>YES</string>` in the above answer its  `<true/>` i was going through my `info.plist`

Comment: Its the same answer, just a different syntax / style.