# Invalid Bundle. iPad Mutlitasking support requires launch story board in bundle

Tags: ios, xcode7, universal

While uploading App to AppStore from XCode 7 then I am getting the below error.

Invalid Bundle. iPad Mutlitasking support requires launch story board in bundle

UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft, UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557783/invalid-bundle-error-requires-launch-story-board

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem in this way:

[image]

This is because you need to specify how your app is supposed to handle multitasking on iPad.