# Why delete UILaunchStoryboardName would resize the ios app window size?

Tags: ios, iphone

1. create a ios single view project.
2. delete storyboard.
3. create a view controller and init it with following code.

   ```
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   ViewController* controller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
   self.window.rootViewController = controller;
   BNRHypnosisView* view = [[BNRHypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   controller.view = view;
   self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   ```
4. delete the info.plist `Launch screen interface base name` which is `UILaunchStoryboardName` entry.
5. the app window size would be smaller than the undeleted one.
   [image: big one]
   [image: small one]
   Why is there such difference since the `LaunchScreen.xib` is deleted? IMO, the compiler or linker should report error since the xib is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presence and use of the Launch storyboard indicates to iOS that you've intentionally considered how your app will look on all devices.  This is similar to how the 568 pixel launch image indicated iPhone support when it came out - otherwise your app will look like the screenshot you took.  It seems Apple is relying on the Launch storyboard more and more lately to allow developers to indicate that their app is intended for all size classes, orientations, and devices, as use of it is also required for iPad multitasking mode.

**Other references:**

- [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12502356/209867)
- [Invalid Bundle Error - “requires launch story board”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557783/invalid-bundle-error-requires-launch-story-board)

Comment: but I have deleted the stoyboard file.

Comment: so add it back.  Is that your question, how to restore the original?

Comment: I mean since I deleted it, why it still functional.

Comment: To me, it looks like it is not functional, that's why you are seeing the window resized.

Comment: I mean I have deleted the storyboard file not the xml entry in the plist. I could name the entry with any value, the value it self does not matter the storyboard file does not matters but the entry itself matter.

Comment: Ok, so what's your question?  It's lack of a storyboard that is causing the issue.

Comment: I mean If I deleted the file, the entry only should not make any difference.