# SwiftUI: App Store Connect Operation Error itms-90476

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, app-store-connect

I work on Xcode 12.1 with SwiftUI

When I send my App (archive) the following error occurs:

ERROR ITMS-90476: "Invalid Bundle. Your app supports Multitasking on iPad, so you must include the launch storyboard file, '...', in your bundle, '...'. Learn more ( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection )."

How can I fix this? I want iPhone and iPad support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid Bundle Error - "requires launch storyboard"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557783/invalid-bundle-error-requires-launch-storyboard)

Comment: Is there a way to handle this with multitasking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a “Adapt multitasking enhancements on iPad” guide

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForSlideOverAndSplitView.html

Also, I’m pretty sure there are some WWDC videos and some sample code.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/supporting_multiple_windows_on_ipad