# ERROR ITMS-90475: Invalid bundle, with RAD Studio

Tags: xcode, app-store, multitasking, info.plist, rad-studio

I created an app with RAD Studio.
I'm trying to publish it to the App Store.
When I try to upload it with Transporter application I verify the package and I obtain following error:

> ERROR ITMS-90475: Invalid bundle. Apps that support Multitasking on
> iPad must provide the app’s launch screen using an Xcode storyboard,
> or using UILaunchScreen if the app’s MinimumOSVersion is 14 or higher.
> Verify that the UILaunchStoryboardName key is included in your
> it.xxx.yyy bundle if you’re using a storyboard. For
> details, see:
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uilaunchstoryboardname

I found [some solutions for this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32557783/505893), but using Xcode or Xamarin. How can I deal with it in RAD Studio? I tried many ways but I just got parsing errors for the *.info.plist file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem creating my app from scratch directly with Xcode, without RAD Studio, as my app was very simple.