# Invalid bundle. Because your app supports Multitasking on iPad, you need to include the LaunchScreen.storyboard launch storyboard file in your

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

When uploading an App to AppStore connect i get the following error:

Invalid bundle. Because your app supports Multitasking on iPad, you need to include the LaunchScreen.storyboard launch storyboard file in your ... bundle.

It is really odd since i do think the file is included in the bundle:

[image]

I also do have "UILaunchStoryboardName" set as "LaunchScreen.storyboard" in Info.Plist.

This appears to have started in xCode 14.1 and i had no issue with this previously.

I do want the iPad app to support multitasking therefore i do not want to set "Requires full screen"

Comment: Do you actually have a storyboard named `LaunchScreen` in your project and is it targeted correctly? When you run your app on an iPad (real or simulated) does the launch screen appear briefly when the app starts?

Comment: yes, I do and when I did run on a simulator the Launch Screen did work and appear as expected. I only got this error when trying to distribute the app. What ended up working was the suggestion: "I cleared the Launch Screen File drop down list and then edited the Info.Plist "Launch screen interface file base name" from "LaunchScreen.storyboard" to only "LaunchScreen" and that solved the issue."

Comment: My issue was that I was setting `Launch screen interface file base name` to `LaunchScreen.storyboard`. The solution was to remove the extension - I only had to provide `LaunchScreen`

Comment: See the answer to [Invalid Bundle Error - "requires launch storyboard"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74744786/20386264) for a quick way to fix.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue. I cleared the Launch Screen File drop down list and then edited the Info.Plist "Launch screen interface file base name" from "LaunchScreen.storyboard" to only "LaunchScreen" and that solved the issue.

Here is where you change it in Info.plist both in xCode visual and text editors:
[image: visual Info.plist editor]
[image: code Info.plist editor]

Comment: I'm not sure if you directly edited the Info.Plist file or used the[Info] tab on the project. I  modified the project by changing the string value of the "Launch screen interface file base name" key and simply removed the .storyboard the [Info] tab.

Comment: If you open Info.Plist in Xcode the UI is the same as the Info tab on the project, they are both editing the Info.Plist file. I used the UI in Xcode to edit the file.

Comment: I had this exact same issue in a React Native app when using `react-native-bootsplash`. It seems that using the dropdown field in the Targets section of the Project Navigator (General Tab -> App Icons and Launch Screen -> Launch Screen File) causes the `UILaunchStoryboardName` key in `Info.plist` to be set with the `.storyboard` extension. Removing the extension manually from the `Info.plist` file solved the issue for me too.

Comment: This worked for me. xcode doesn't like the ".storyboard" extension that it ITSELF created. Yet another reason to absolutely hate this dumpster-fire of a program.

Comment: thanks @TomSpencer! Same issue in my case

Answer (score 1):

Specify the name of the storyboard file without the filename extension. For example, if the filename of your storyboard is LaunchScreen.storyboard, specify "LaunchScreen" as the value for this key.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uilaunchstoryboardname

Answer (score -2):

I cleaned my build folder and archived again. Somehow that fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

I had exactly the same issue.
but i my case salutation is in info plist entry is missing.
so i think you can use this option.

```
key : Launch screen interface file base name
value : {your launch screen name}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUBvO.png)